# MS Access 2010 SQL Top 3 Sales in Group by

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with columns such as year, quarter, team and price. it shows every sale from the team. We have 10 teams in the firm. 
I want to know for each quarter of each year, which three teams sold the most overall. So where am I stuck? At this point I grouped the total sales per team, per quarter, per year. Still missingt o only get the three best teams with highest sales. I got this so far:

```
SELECT 
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team,
    sum(a1.price) as Total

FROM
    tbl_sales a1    

inner JOIN
    tbl_sales a2 
        ON a1.year = a2.year
            and a1.quarter = a2.quarter
            and a1.team = a2.team
            and a1.price = a2.price
     where
           some restrictions here
GROUP BY
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team
```

Something tells me I am close, that just a subquery with the top function will help but I just can't figure it out. Any help is very much appreciated :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add `ORDER BY Total DESC` at the end. Does Access support `SELECT TOP 3`?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ALL-DISTINCT-DISTINCTROW-TOP-Predicates-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57 says that TOP is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team,
    sum(a1.price) as Total

FROM
    tbl_sales a1    

inner JOIN
    tbl_sales a2 
        ON a1.year = a2.year
            and a1.quarter = a2.quarter
            and a1.team = a2.team
            and a1.price = a2.price
     where
           some restrictions here
GROUP BY
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team

ORDER BY 
    sum(a1.price) DESC
```

Edit, try the following, you might need additional criteria to ensure you get the correct resultset but this should return the top 3 of each quarter that is specified in the where clause, I don't know why you are using a self join so I left that out but it can be added back in if necessary:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team,
    sum(a1.price) as Total

FROM
    tbl_sales a1

WHERE
     'some restrictions here'
     AND a1.quarter = 1 --(or however quarters are identified)
     AND a1.year = 2015 --(or however years are identified)

GROUP BY
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team

ORDER BY 
    sum(a1.price) DESC

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 3
    a2.year,
    a2.quarter,
    a2.team,
    sum(a2.price) as Total

FROM
    tbl_sales a2

WHERE
    'some restrictions here'
    AND a2.quarter = 2
    AND a2.year = 2015

GROUP BY
    a2.year,
    a2.quarter,
    a2.team

ORDER BY 
    sum(a2.price) DESC

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 3
    a3.year,
    a3.quarter,
    a3.team,
    sum(a3.price) as Total

FROM
    tbl_sales a3

WHERE
    'some restrictions here'
    AND a3.quarter = 3
    AND a3.year = 2015

GROUP BY
    a3.year,
    a3.quarter,
    a3.team

ORDER BY 
    sum(a3.price) DESC

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 3
    a1.year,
    a1.quarter,
    a1.team,
    sum(a1.price) as Total

FROM
    tbl_sales a4

WHERE
    'some restrictions here'
    AND a4.quarter = 4
    AND a4.year = 2015

GROUP BY
    a4.year,
    a4.quarter,
    a4.team

ORDER BY 
    sum(a4.price) DESC
```

As you can see there is basically no difference between the tables except the where clause, you aren't limited to a union of just those 4 tables, it is just an example but just keep in mind that if you need to cover more quarters you will need to add more tables to be unioned. This can get very unwieldy as it requires you to keep adding tables to the union as time goes on.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time!! This gives me the highest team sales per year ranging all quarters. i also need per quarter as well....closer though :)

Comment: In order to do that you will probably need to create a separate table for each quarter then union them all together, this will append each quarter with the top 3 teams to the resultset and give you what you are looking for.

Comment: any quick idea how to do that?

Comment: It might be tough given I don't know the structure of the tables, the data contained within them or the pks/fks. One question I have is whether you actually need a1.price = a2.price or a1.team = a2.team, are these necessary in order for the data to align correctly? I'll update the answer with a general solution that should set you on the right path.

Comment: you were right. works now. i just had every quarter separately as subselect and used union to put all together.. best thanks mate! appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you can do this using `IN` with `TOP`:

```
select s.*
from tbl_sales as s
where s.team in (select top (3) s2.team
                 from tbl_sales as s2
                 where s2.year = s.year and s2.quarter = s.quarter
                 order by s2.price desc
                );
```

You may need to add the restrictions both to the outer query and the inner query, depending on what they are.